# Xcode LLVM 5.0 Error -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, compiler-errors, llvm-clang

I am getting the following error in Xcode 5.1: clang: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-check' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

My operating system is OSx Mavericks 10.9.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since this would allow my brother to complete the work for Stanford CS106b.  I am aware that this question has been asked before on SO, but I have been unsuccessful after four hours of trying suggestions including:

- Adding -fstack-check to the compiler flags under Compile Sources.
- Typing export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" in Terminal
- Adding 'ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future' to ~/.bash_profile
- Editing Scheme in Xcode, setting ARCHFLAGS to -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
- Adding a .plist file with ARCHFLAGS set to -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future

All of these attempts have resulted in the same error popping up when I click build.  Here is the full error:

---

clang: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-check' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-check' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
Command

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

---

I will REALLY appreciate a solution since this has been consuming hours of my time, and it will give my brother a productive coding environment.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that 'fstack-check' isn't compatible with LLVM 5.0. I've tried compiling the C++ projects on XCode 5, XCode 6 beta on both Mavericks and Yosemite to no avail.

Finally I just installed XCode 4.6.3 it compiled without errors with LLVM 4. Just download it from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and it should work fine. Hopefully Stanford does release some updates to their existing libraries so it'll be compatible with the later versions of LLVM.